# H2 database: Does a 60 second write delay have adverse effects on db health?

Tags: h2, corruption, embedded-database

We're currently using H2 version 199 in embedded mode with default nio file protocol and MVStore storage system. The write_delay parameter is set to 60 seconds.

We run a batch insert/update/delete of about 30.000 statements within 2 seconds (in one transaction) followed by another batch of a couple of hundred statements only 30 seconds later (in a second transaction). The next attempt to open a db connection (only 2 minutes later) shows that the DB is corrupt:

```
File corrupted while reading record: null. Possible solution: use the recovery tool [90030-199]
```

Since the transactions occur within a minute, we wonder whether the write_delay of 60 seconds might be contributing to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Changing write_delay to 60s (from a default value of 0.5s) will definitely increase your risk of lost transactions, and I do not see a good reason for doing it. Should not cause a db corruption, though. More likely some thread interruptions do that, since you are running in the same JVM a web server and who knows what else. Using async file store might help in that area, and yes it is stable enough (how much worse it can go for your app, than a database corruption, anyway).

Comment: Hi @andrei, the batch operations are rarely performed (once every couple of months). They are application data updates from a central server. Apart from that we usually do not see any DB corruptions. The asnyc protocol is still flagged as experimental by the H2 community. Could you please elaborate on why you deem the protocol to be stable. Please feel free to answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68078765/h2-database-is-the-async-file-protocol-safe-to-use